# Is it impossible to preview and test dynamic content within a Salesforce Data Journey?

Tags: marketing-cloud

We are using a lot of dynamic content within a Salesforce Data Journey but the only thing we can do to preview and test is to create a test lead, but we'd have to create over 50 to truly test each component. Am I missing something?

Comment: No not really, if you really want to test all your variations of dynamics, you will need to run multiple test cases through to cover off all your expected use cases. There isn't any way to visually produce all the 50 outcomes without providing the data to reference.

Comment: ahh, I see okay well at least I know I'm not missing anything. Thanks!

Comment: Please find an answer I think you can use below, @BoLt - do accept it if it helps you along

Answer (score 2):

When you create a Salesforce Data Entry, it also creates an underlying Data Extension in the root folder with following naming: [Journey name] - [Created time] - e.g.: *Welcome new customers - 2019-02-28T143210524*

It contains all the fields you select in your Entry Data:
[image]

If you have already published one version of the journey, you will be able to copy that Data Extension, and crate a copy for test purposes, populating it with dummy data covering your needs for all the variations. If you are still yet to create your first version, you can do a "handheld" creation of a test DE, where you create all the fields, observing the *Object:Field* notation - however, I admit it is a cumbersome process, especially if you are dealing with substantial set of fields in Journey Data.

You can then use this Data Extension in Content Builder, Preview and Test tab.

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer No, If you really want to test all your variations, you will need to run multiple test cases to cover off all your expected use cases. There isn't any way to visually produce all the 50 outcomes without providing the data to reference.